# Updating the database on click of a table row

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am having a table in which data is being populated through the database.Now what i want is that as soon as i click on one of the row a alert message displays and the READSTATUS of that row become true in my database that is database gets updated .

Now my problem is where to write the code for updating the database as i dont want to move to a different page to do so.

Like my table is something like this :

```
<input type=hidden name="notifyidd" id="notifyidd" value="<%=messageid%>"/> 
<tr bgcolor="#5D1B90" color="#FFFFFF" onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true,false);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false,false);" onclick="DoNav('shownotification.jsp?mid=<%=messageid%>');"> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick="DoRemove(event);"  width="20" class="select_all_mail" value=<%=messageid%>></td>
<td callspan="3" width="1000px"><%=messagesubject%>  at   <%=sendingtime%></td>

</tr>
```

and in onclick method of each row i had called the alert.But how to update the database now ?

```
function DoNav(theUrl)
 {

    var tt = document.myinbox.notifyidd.value;
    alert(tt);
  //document.location.href = theUrl;
  }
```

As if i uncomment this line then it will move to next page.But i want to do it on same page only.Please help

EDIT :

I wrote a ajax code to do it.But it gives error.Please help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myrow').click(function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "shownotification.jsp", //this is my servlet
            data: {
                notifyidd: $('#notifyidd').val()

            },
            success: function(msg){      
                    if(msg == "success")
                    alert('Data updated.');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Here i assign myrow as id to my table row.Also i removed doNav function now

My error image clicked :

http://postimg.org/image/vix1vzvq5/

Though the error is resolved but this ajax call is not functioning.For test i make my shownotification.jsp as :

```
<body>
    <% String notifyid = request.getParameter("notifyidd");%>
    success
</body>
```

Comment: You need some server-interaction do update the database. The database is on the server right? Maybe read about Ajax.

Comment: @phylax yeah ,I am reading ajax.But what will be code for it in jsp page ?

Comment: jsp has nothing to with javascript. Ask a question 'how to update database with jsp'.

Comment: isn't it localstorage/SQLite clientside database?

Comment: @vp_arth yeah, but i dont read anything about localstorage in OP

Comment: @phylax, aha) it was my question to OP)

Comment: Answer: you should transfer data from your browser to database, often people selected ajax http to some http server for this.

Comment: @phylax i wrote ajax code.But please help me find mistake in it

Comment: @user3499007 if you are getting an error, please include the exact error message.

Comment: @BenGartner i posted a pic link of my error.

Comment: `Java NPE`... no groupid attr in your session?

Comment: @vp_arth It was just because of some server problem.Its resolved but on click of a row the ajax call does nt do the work

Comment: Sure you `if(msg=='success')` is correct, you return html with `<body>` isn't it?

Comment: @vp_arth i didnt get you?is my test jsp program wrong u mean?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says the server-side code is failing when looking for the attribute `"groupid"`. The post you are sending has `notifyidd` instead. The server code has no way of knowing if this should map to `groupid` or not.

Try this. If it doesn't work, update us with the error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myrow').click(function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "shownotification.jsp", //this is my servlet
            data: {
                groupid: $('#notifyidd').val()

            },
            success: function(msg){      
                    if(msg == "success")
                    alert('Data updated.');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: That error was just due to some IDE problem .I restarted it and it worked But the ajasx call is not  working when i test it for a sample jsp code(i edited my post please check)